# Outlook 2010 shows time one hour ahead

Tags: c#, outlook, timezone, icalendar

I have created following ".ics" file. When I open it in Google and iCal it shows correct time but when I open in Outlook 2010 it shows time one hour ahead. Any help?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//www.marudot.com//iCal Event Maker
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140510T110000
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140510T111500
SUMMARY:Appointment-11:00 AM-PST
DESCRIPTION:Appointment-11:00 AM-PST
LOCATION:Location: TBD
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2):

When using local time with timezone, adding a TZID to all date related properties is not enough. That is because there is no global registry of TZID that is understood by all clients. Hence, one must include in the iCalendar stream the timezone definition that corresponds to this TIZD.

In other words, your stream is not iCalendar compliant. Before the event (before BEGIN:VEVENT), you should have a proper VTIMEZONE definition corresponding to the TZID America/Los_Angeles. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.3.1

In your case, it would be something like:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
DTSTART:20070311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
DTSTART:20071104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "TZID=America/Los_Angeles" is a time zone that Outlook understand. Try to create a an appointment in Outlook and save it as an ICS file. What TZ does Outlook use?